# How to put multithreading with boto3 S3 paginator?

Tags: python-3.x, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, boto3, opensearch

I have logs sized around 200GB each day in s3. I wrote a script to read from s3 with boto3 paginator and writing it to opensearch. The problem I am facing is the script is too slow to index all data. Its taking around 4 days to index 1 day of logs in s3. My script currently looks like below. I am not sure how to put multithreading with paginators and also make it thread safe. Any suggestion for faster alternative for this would also be appreciated.

```
import sys
import json
import logging
import boto3
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, RequestsHttpConnection, AWSV4SignerAuth

globalVars = {}
globalVars['Environment'] = ""
globalVars['awsRegion'] = ""
globalVars['Bucket'] = ""
globalVars['osIndexPrefix'] = ""
index_name = ''
globalVars['osHosts'] = ""

# Initialize Logger
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)


def indexDocElement(obj_list):
    try:
        credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
        auth = AWSV4SignerAuth(credentials, globalVars['awsRegion'])

        client = OpenSearch(
            hosts=[{'host': globalVars['osHosts'], 'port': 443}],
            http_auth=auth,
            use_ssl=True,
            verify_certs=True,
            connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
        )

        client.bulk(body=obj_list, index=index_name)

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('ERROR: {0}'.format(str(e)))
        logger.error('ERROR: Unable to index line')

def get_s3_object(s3, log_date):
    try:
        paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
        operation_parameters = {'Bucket': globalVars['Bucket'],
                                'Prefix': 'eks/'+log_date,
                                'PaginationConfig': {'PageSize': 100}}
        page_iterator = paginator.paginate(**operation_parameters)

        for page in page_iterator:
            if page['KeyCount'] > 0:
                for item in page['Contents']:
                    yield item

    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('ERROR: {0}'.format(str(e)))
        logger.error(
            'ERROR: Unable able to GET object:{0} from S3 Bucket:{1}. Verify object exists.'.format('eks/'+log_date, globalVars['Bucket']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')

    log_date = sys.argv[1]
    print("\nDate:", log_date)


    index_string = '{"index": {}}'

    for i in get_s3_object(s3, log_date):
        if i['Key'].split('/')[-1]== '':
            print(len(i['Key'].split('/')))
            continue
        obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=globalVars['Bucket'], Key=i['Key'])
        j = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
        obj_list = j.split('\n')
        intermediate_item_list = []
        for obj in obj_list:
            if obj == '':
                continue
            obj = json.loads(obj)
            obj['@timestamp'] = obj['date']
            del obj['kubernetes']['labels']
            obj = json.dumps(obj)
            intermediate_item_list.append(obj)

        item_list = []
        for item in intermediate_item_list:
            item_list.append(index_string)
            item_list.append(item)

        item_list = '\n'.join(item_list)
        indexDocElement(item_list)
```

Comment: You can't parallelize listing objects.  The [underlying API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html) requires data from page x-1 for page x.  If you want to get list a large number of objects, it's best to setup a [S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) report and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference on GitHub from [here](https://gist.github.com/gudgud96/bdde37c9cc6b56a88ae3a7a0a217a723). He is first creating a list of keys and then applies multithreading to download the keys from the list. I tried this in my script and was able to reduce the time taken from 4 days to ~6 hours.